# Why one same USIM card has two IMSI?

Tags: android

I want to get IMSI invoking TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId(), but sometimes get 334050xxxxxx, and sometimes get 222013xxxxxx, why? I use the some one USIM card.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your card has Dual IMSI application (or Multi IMSI application). One IMSI is used for home and partners network, and another one for international use (roaming).

I suggest to use ICCID for identification, because it is unique for each card. You can use [Telephony#getSimSerialNumber()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).